# Jython stalls on 1 = 2

Tags: jython

I have been investigating jython a bit, and at the jython terminal accidentally typed `1 = 2` instead of `q = 2`, and found this:

```
>>> 1 = 2
...
...
```

I had to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get out of it. No other input seems to make it happy.

I put the same code in a script and ran it with the same behavior (it just hangs).

In CPython, I get a SyntaxError: can't assign to literal (as expected).

Any idea what's going on? Is this just a jython bug?

```
$ jython
Jython 2.5.2 (Debian:hg/91332231a448, Jun 3 2012, 09:02:34) 
[OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.7.0_51
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug with Jython. (Incidentally, typing `\X` for any `X` on the next line ends the statement and triggers the correct error.)

Comment: I'd report the bug at the Jython bug tracker: http://bugs.jython.org/